# I want to retrieve numbers from string whose character start from 8 OR 9 OR 6 and followed by 8 digits

Tags: c#, regex

I want to retrieve numbers from string whose character start from 8 OR 9 OR 6 and is followed by 8 digits.

E.G

```
sting string string  85689252 91585555 65987582  sting 12345678 string
```

Output should be:

```
85689252 
91585555 
65987582
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want this regex:

```
\b[896]\d{7}\b
```

I assume that the numbers are at least separated by some character other than alphanumeric and `_`, so I used `\b` to match word boundary.

If you want to relax the condition, the regex engine must support look ahead and look behind:

```
(?<!\d)[896]\d{7}(?!\d)
```

In this case, I just make sure the whole number is not preceded or followed by any digit.

Your question says followed by 8 digits, but it seems you mean the whole number should have 8 digits - so I changed my answer according to your sample input.

Use [`Regex.Matches`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to get all the string that matches the regex.

Comment: i am retrieving only this string 85689252 using your code,not all 85689252 
91585555 
65987582 string.

Comment: @lipid: Show your code. You should use `Matches`, not `Match`